# ValueError: Related model u'app.model' cannot be resolved when running tests

Tags: python, django, testing, valueerror

I am trying to run some tests on a Django project (Django version 1.11.4)
using Python 3.5.0.

I have 2 applications inside my project: uploads and testgen.

Those are my models:

(Here there are only the special fields, like the relationships fields. The rest of the fields are CharField, PositiveIntegerField and BooleanField mainly.)

uploads\models.py

(a simplified version)

```
class Document(models.Model):
    (any relationship fields)


class Word(models.Model):
    synonyms = models.ManyToManyField("self")
    antonyms = models.ManyToManyField("self")


class Sentence(models.Model):
    words = models.ManyToManyField(Word)


class Paragraph(models.Model):
    sentences = models.ManyToManyField(Sentence)


class Text(models.Model):
    document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    paragraphs = models.ManyToManyField(Paragraph)
```

testgen\models.py

(a simplified version)

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    content = models.OneToOneField(Sentence,
                                   related_name="issue_content",
                                   null=True)
    question = models.OneToOneField(Sentence, null=True)


class FillableIssue(Issue):
    replaceable_words = models.ManyToManyField(Word)


class StatementIssue(Issue):
    replaceable_words = models.ManyToManyField(Word)


class AppTest(models.Model):
    text = models.ForeignKey(Text, null=True)
    fillable_issues = models.ManyToManyField(FillableIssue)
    statement_issues = models.ManyToManyField(StatementIssue)
```

testgen\tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from testgen.models import AppTest


class AppTestTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_apptest_has_positive_number_issues(self):

        """
            has_positive_number_issues() returns True
            if the test's number issues is greater than zero.
        """

        app_tests = AppTest.objects.get_queryset().all()
        for app_test in app_tests:
            self.assertIs(app_test.has_positive_number_issues(), True)
```

project settings file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'uploads',
'testgen',
]
```

Note: I use the uploads models inside the testgen models for the application logic.

I suspect that the model's name could be the problem ('AppTest')

The traceback can be inspected in the screenshots images.

[first capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iElFR.jpg)
[second capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR4KQ.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have deleted all migration files from other apps and run makemigrations and migrate again.

Everything works now.